# Big Query - Only insert if column value does not exist

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

Does Big Query support operations like "REPLACE INSERT" or something related to that?

If I run a query like this twice:

```
INSERT INTO table(column1) VALUES(1)
```

It'll create a duplicated row, is it possible to insert a row only if a column with the same value does not exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below should make it

```
#standardSQL
INSERT INTO yourTable(column1)
SELECT value FROM (SELECT 1 AS value) 
LEFT JOIN yourTable  
ON column1 = value
WHERE column1 IS NULL
```

Comment: can you explain the statement?

Answer (score 6):

Does this work for you?

```
INSERT INTO table(column1)
WITH s AS (SELECT 1 src)
SELECT src FROM s WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM table t WHERE t.column1 = s.src
)
```